# Populate List strings one element at a time in textarea

Tags: jsp, session, servlets, textarea, jstl

I am using an `HttpSession session` and `session.setAttribute("property_name", list_of_strings);` to populate a `List<String>` in a jsp `<textarea><c:forEach var="word" items="${property_name}">${word}</c:forEach>` but I want the text to populate the List one item at a time and in a new row. Can someone tell me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and use this HTML character for line separator in textarea:

```
        &#10;
```

In your code:

```
        <c:forEach var="word" items="${property_name}">${word} &#10;</c:forEach>
```

Comment: That worked thanks :) a lot but can you explain to me what this special char does?

Comment: Great to hear that! I also used it as a line separator in text area, and from what I researched there is no better alternative.